# Add a custom row in Woocommerce edit order pages

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am looking to insert a custom string in the order page but only for certain products. I have a subscription with a sign-up fee which is payable immediately and then a recurring monthly payment which the user can choose when to start.

I would like to add a custom string for all recurring products with a sign up fee on the "your order page. (if possible otherwise per product - one of the products's product Id '11349')

Currently I feel it is going to be confusing for the clients. By adding a Payable now string the client will know exactly what they need to pay now and what will be reccuring
See image on link https://fundance.co.za/order-page-string/ as to where I would like to add my custom string.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents" refer this hook to add custom string before cart content of order page.

"woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents" refer this hook to add custom string after cart content of order page.

"woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity" Using this filter we can update quantity in order page and we can append string also, Kindly refer the hook for custom string in you mentioned area in order page.

For More checkout hook for reference.,
https://www.wpdesk.net/blog/woocommerce-checkout-hooks/#lightbox/0/

Comment: Thank you so much. But I think I have now broke it. I have added it with snippets and it showed up but on the wrong spot. I have tried to edit it but now it is just gone. I have deactivated the snippet and tried a new one but It is not appearing again

Comment: I have use the following add function add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'payable_now');
function payable_now() {
    if ( ! is_ajax() ) {
        echo 'Payable Now';
    }
}   But it is displaying on top of the Product and not after cart contents. Am I doing something wrong?